# How will backend analytics such as health monitoring and business intelligence work for EOS dApps?

Tags: dapp

Centralized apps often use tools like [New Relic](https://newrelic.com/) to monitor their health in real-time. The use of business intelligence analytics platforms like [Tableau](https://www.tableau.com/) is also common practice. Can the same tools be used by dApps? If not, what are the alternatives? What are the few things to keep in mind while planning for backend analytics while building on EOS?

Comment: Well what is analytics reporting? Data from store being retrieved and displayed in a UI. So by that logic - yes, analytics reporting can be done over EOS. An account can store data on/across block producers (will cost you for storage), and the account can then retrieve JSON data related to those tables (will cost you for bandwidth), as well as compute some stats (will cost you for RAM). Slap a UI on it and you've got a dashboard